# bug ember computed with setter and getter

Tags: ember.js

so. I have this in my component.js :

```js
…
inputs: Ember.A(),

inputGroup: computed('inputs.[]', {
    get() {
      return this.get('inputs').mapBy('value');
    },
    set(_, values) {
     # breakpoint 1
      if (values) {
        values.forEach(value => {
          this.get('inputs').addObject({ id: Symbol(), value: value });
        });
      }
     # breakpoint 2
      return this.get('inputs').mapBy('value');
    },
  }),
...
```

and I have 2 of this component in my app.hbs :

```html
{{addon-component inputGroup=firstGroup … }} {{addon-component inputGroup=secondGroup … }}
```

with app.js :

```js
…
firstGroup: Ember.A([’text@text.com’]),
secondGroup: Ember.A(),
…
```

in my first component, debugger on `# breakpoint 1`, `inputs  === []`, on `# breakpoint 2`, `inputs === ['test@test.com']`
in my second one, debugger on `# breakpoint 1`, already `inputs === [‘text@text.com’]`.
How is that possible ??

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on here without more details. You best bet would be to use https://ember-twiddle.com/ and create a reproduction of the issue you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't declare arrays or objects directly on components. Arrays or objects declared this way are shared among component instances. You need to declare them inside init hook, that way they will be set independent for every component instance. So you need to declare inputs this way.

```
//inside component
init() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  this.set('inputs', Ember.A());
}
```

From [the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_initializing-instances):

> Arrays and objects defined directly on any Ember.Object are shared
>   across all instances of that object.